# Array to Object First and Last

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to take the first and last element in a given array and return an object with the first element as the key and the last as the value.

Here's my code:

```
function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
    array=[];
    var object={}; 
    object[key]=value;// make object
    var key=array[0];
    var value=array[array.length-1];

    return object;} // return object
```

for whatever reason, it's returning undefined inside the object. I swear it was working this morning...

I've always tried:

```
 function  transformFirstAndLast(array) {
     array=[];
     var object = {}; 
     object[array[0]] = array[array.length-1];}
```

but that's returning undefined without so much as an object being built.

Comment: Why are you reassigning `array`...?

Comment: you add the undefined key with an undefined value to object ... and THEN assign values to key and value? ... javascript does not work that way ... `object[key]=value;// make object` should be just before the return statement

Comment: because when I don't, it claims it  'cannot read property '0' of undefined'...trust me, I don't want it there.

Comment: and in your second code block, you clobber the incoming array before reading it!!

Comment: because in both codes you set `array=[]` as the first line ... thereby losing the incoming array!!

Comment: @Jaromanda X I'm aware of that, that's just a silly mistake from things being shuffled around as a last ditch attempt to solve the problem. Even with 'object[key]=value;' where it should be, it still returns undefined inside the object.

Comment: not if you put the code in the right order

Comment: @BellamyGray Jaramonda's already told you the reason for undefined! You immediately reassign `array` to *an empty array* so it has nothing and trying to access an index will give you undefined! Remove the first line in the function!

Comment: again, the array=[ ] is only there because without it, either way, it returns an error statement 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined'

Comment: @BellamyGray What are you passing as an argument to the function...?

Comment: your code, with the changes I mentioned - https://jsfiddle.net/934gbzuv/

Comment: `because without it` - you're calling `transformFirstAndLast` incorrectly then

Comment: @Andrew Li...oversight on my part calling the function. sorry guys! thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're redeclaring `array` at the beggining of your function.

Besides, **in my opinion**, using "array" and "object" as variable names is a bad idea. Just a typo could get you messing up with Array and Object. And that might have side effects.

Here's a functional fiddle for your use case using array.shift() and array.pop() methods.

```js
var myArray=['one','two','three','four'];

function buildObject(arr) {
  var myObject={},
      key=arr.shift(),
      val=arr.pop();

  myObject[key]=val;
  return myObject;
}

console.log(buildObject(myArray));
```

Comment: `using "array" and "object" as variable names is a very bad idea` - how so? `array` and `object` are perfectly reasonable names in such a generic function

Comment: Why are `array` and `object` bad variable names? It's not redeclaring `array`, it's reassigning `array` to an empty array, essentially throwing away the passed objects...

Comment: Because it's easy to get entangled with primitives with just an innocent typo.

Comment: I use "array" and "object" as variable names because as I learn, it's the most intuitive and readable as I work/read over my code again and again. I imagine once I'm a bit more proficient I will be a bit more creative.  I swear, sometimes this community is too quick to pass judgement.

Comment: @amenadiel What primitives?

Comment: I'm not judginh you, mate. I'll rephrase that statement to be less judgemental. I didn't intended it to be picky

Comment: @AndrewLi I'm sorry. Native objects.

Comment: This mutates `arr`, which is probably not a Good Thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward using computed property names:

```
function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
  return {[array[0]]: array[array.length - 1]};
}
```

Or if you prefer:

```
const transformFirstAndLast = ([head, ...tail]) => ({[head]: tail.pop()});
```